# Synchronize 2 separate scrollbars in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, scrollbar, angular8

I have a sidenav inside of another sidenav, each with their own scrollbar. I want to find a way to synchronize both of them so when one scrolls up or down the other one does the same.

Here's the code structure in my HTML file:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container"> ---> CONTAINER 1

   <mat-sidenav class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="false" mode="side" role="navigation" opened="true" >
      <mat-nav-list>
          *group of mat-list-item*
      </mat-nav-list>
   </mat-sidenav>

   <mat-sidenav-content>

      <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container"> ---> CONTAINER 2
          <mat-sidenav class="secondSidenav" fixedInViewport="false" mode="side" role="navigation" opened="true">
              <mat-nav-list>
                 *group of mat-list-item*
              </mat-nav-list>
          </mat-sidenav>
          <mat-sidenav-content> *something* </mat-sidenav-content>
       </mat-sidenav-container>

   </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

The scrollbars are from the mat-sidenav-containers. I want to sychronize the scrollbars from container 1 and container 2.

Here's an image of the scrollbars:
[image]

I've tried some things but none work. What can I try?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz with the example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Probably by using `HTMLElement` and with `scroll` event we can achieve this.
I have update the code snippet with scroll event for both the *mat-sidenav's*

1. First mat-sidenav add this event **(scroll)="updateLeftScroll(scrollOne, scrollTwo)" #scrollOne**
2. Second mat-sidenav add this event **(scroll)="updateRightScroll(scrollTwo, scrollOne)" #scrollTwo**

As shown below

> *.HTML*

```
    <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
   <mat-sidenav class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="false" mode="side" role="navigation" opened="true" (scroll)="updateLeftScroll(scrollOne, scrollTwo)" #scrollOne>
      <mat-nav-list>
          *group of mat-list-item*
      </mat-nav-list>
   </mat-sidenav>

   <mat-sidenav-content>

      <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
          <mat-sidenav class="secondSidenav" fixedInViewport="false" mode="side" role="navigation" opened="true" (scroll)="updateRightScroll(scrollTwo, scrollOne)" #scrollTwo>
              <mat-nav-list>
                 *group of mat-list-item*
              </mat-nav-list>
          </mat-sidenav>
          <mat-sidenav-content> *something* </mat-sidenav-content>
       </mat-sidenav-container>

   </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

> *.ts*

```
   updateLeftScroll(scrollOne: HTMLElement, scrollTwo: HTMLElement){
     scrollTwo.scrollTop = scrollOne.scrollTop;
     scrollTwo.scrollBy = scrollOne.scrollBy;
  } 
  updateRightScroll(scrollTwo: HTMLElement, scrollOne: HTMLElement) {
    scrollOne.scrollTop = scrollTwo.scrollTop;
    scrollOne.scrollBy = scrollTwo.scrollBy;
  }
```

*Note*: the above two lines of code enough to sync the two scroll bars, If need any other logic need to perform can write our own logic in the methods.

Comment: This is giving me an error: argument of type 'MatSidenav' is not assignable to parameter of type HTMLElement

I tried changing HTMLElement to Element but it throws the same error.
I also tried using @ViewChild and ElementRef to mitigate this error, and while the error no longer appears, it does nothing.

Comment: May be you can add a DIV on top of the MatSidenav and apply this scroll event to that div some thing like 

`<div  (scroll)="updateLeftScroll(scrollOne, scrollTwo)" #scrollOne>
<mat-sidenav class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="false" mode="side" role="navigation" opened="true">
      <mat-nav-list>
          *group of mat-list-item*
      </mat-nav-list>
   </mat-sidenav>
</div>`

Comment: @ThomasGM Did you actually set the "read" property to ElementRef of the `@ViewChild`?  Like so: `@ViewChild('scrollOne', { read: ElementRef }) scrollbarOne` ? Also, a little addition to what @SRMKumar wrote: if you are actually using a `@ViewChild` per scrollbar, you don't need to pass the template references to the scrollbars in `updateRightScroll(..)` and `updateRightScroll(...)`, you can instead reference them as: `this.scrollbarOne.nativeElement` or `this.scrollbarTwo.nativeElement` inside the method body.

Comment: @ardentia Yes, I did that but it doesn't really do anything. I thought about using CdkScrollable, but I can't make it work either.

Comment: @ThomasGM Could you provide a StackBlitz example of the issue you are experiencing?